# UILabel aligned to readable guide works on iPad, but not on the phone

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view that is used as header of a section in a table view. It contains a label that is supposed to be aligned to the readable content guide. Works on the iPad, but on the phone: it's not indented at all.

```
let v = UIView(frame: .zero)
let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let attrText = NSMutableAttributedString(...
attrText.addAttributes(titleLabelAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrText.length))

label.attributedText = attrText
label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
v.addSubview(label)

let readableGuide = v.readableContentGuide
readableGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.topAnchor).isActive = true
readableGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.leadingAnchor, constant:0.0).isActive = true
readableGuide.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.trailingAnchor, constant:0.0).isActive = true
```

Why would that be?

Comment: I got this from reading an article, can you try commenting out the `readableGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.topAnchor).isActive = true` and add this instead?
 `label.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)`

Comment: Didn't make a difference, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the iPad was fine only when the font was set to the minimum size in Settings. What resolved the issue was setting "Preserve Superview Margins" on the section header view.